# How do you track on a database a session timeout while the application is closed?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis, timeout

On my .NET web application I need to track down when a session expires while the browser is closed.

Is there any way to do this? I've already handled the case in which a session timeouts while a user is logged-in, but I can't think of a way to detect this particular issue.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Global.asax, add code to the Session_OnEnd method. This event fires whether or not the browser is open.